# Unity: Android App crash with EGL Errorcode 3004

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

Here you can see the log. On some devices it gets stuck in the first screen, but in others (like the log owner), it simply crashes at startup

```
04-15 09:59:34.586 14063-14063/com.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
04-15 09:59:35.589 14063-14101/com.appname W/MALI: __egl_set_error:121: [WARNING]Mali EGL errorcode: 3004
04-15 09:59:35.590 14063-14101/com.appname W/MALI: __egl_set_error:121: [WARNING]Mali EGL errorcode: 3004
04-15 09:59:35.806 853-1235/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{42b07608 u0 com.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t31}: app died, no saved state
04-15 09:59:35.809 853-981/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '42d13898 com.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-15 09:59:35.809 853-981/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '42d13898 com.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-15 09:59:35.809 853-1326/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42d13898 com.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
04-15 09:59:35.809 853-1326/system_process W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{4260ba68 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{42d13898 u0 com.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
```

Comment: You'll [need this](https://www.khronos.org/files/egl-1-4-quick-reference-card.pdf)

Comment: "EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE 0x3004 An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in an attribute list." Ok, what do I do with this?

Comment: Now you know why it's crashing. Stepping with a debugger might also reveal **where** it's crashing. Then hit either Unity3d support or Khronos group's support with the log and perhaps they can help you... on the other hand, pinpoint the vendors and devices on which the problem happens and try to find a workaround for those devices. That's about as much as you can do. If Unity3D is open-source, you may also be able to fix the problem.

Comment: So the issue is the compiler or the devices? Not the code?

Comment: It could be the device's android image. Not a bad rom, but sloppy vendor's work. But you'll have to dig deeper to find out more. Like I said, try pinpointing it to certain vendor/device pairs. E.g. `HTC M8`